# using angularjs and bootstrap3 modalInstance.dismiss('cancel') does not work in IE

Tags: angularjs

I am using
**AngularJS v1.2.6** and **bootstrap 3.0.3**

[this is an example of the problem on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paries/HB7LU/1858/). It works on FF and Chrome, but not IE.

I have this modal dialog, that works great except for when you close it using IE9 on win7

in my controller i have have the following snippet. both `$modalInstance.close(result);` and `$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');` behave the same way with IE. When the dialog is shown you can see the dialog and also see the page data behind via the translucent bg which is expected.

But when i click the close button, the dialog goes away as well as the page behind. It goes completely blank

Anyone else have this problem or know how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

I am editing this because i have found more information.

**This problem only shows itself IF the modal html has an Iframe and the iframe src is a PDF**

```
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="cancel()">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">FRAME</h4>
            </div>

            <iframe src="/pdf-test.pdf"></iframe>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
                <!--   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="close()">Close2</button>-->
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

here is some of the open, but i think really does not matter, because if the src of the iframe is any dialog if exhibits the problem

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/snippets/modal.html?v=3',
            controller: ['$scope', '$modalInstance','modaldata', function($scope, $modalInstance, modaldata) {

                $scope.modaldata = modaldata;

                $scope.submit = function(feedback) {
                    $modalInstance.close({feedback: feedback});
                };

                $scope.close = function(result){
                    $modalInstance.close(result);
                };

                $scope.cancel = function() {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
            }],
            resolve: {
                modaldata: function () {
                    return $scope.modaldata =
                    {
                        'id' : pmIdSeq
                        ,'iframeSRC'    : iframeSRC
                        ,'modaltitle'   : $scope.druggroupslist[arrayIdx].pm_Title
                    };
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make it work. I think this must be a bug in the angularUI stuff.

I had to clear the src of the iframe before calling $modalInstance.close and this seems to now work in IE

```
                $scope.close = function(result){
                    $('#myiframepfg').attr("src",'');//added so IE does not crash and burn
                    $modalInstance.close(result);
                };
```